# jquery get or find dynamic css properties

Tags: jquery, string

I have some css classes applied to `body` and I want to get a particular class that changes dynamically. So, it's like this:

```
<body class="apple mango guava lime-1">
```

What I want to get is `1`.

Now, `lime-1` could change to `lime-2` another time. So, what I want is a way to search all CSS classes in the body and then check if `lime-` exists and get the next value after the hyphen.

I have done this:
`var classes = $('body').attr('class');`

Thanks

Comment: If you can, I'd suggest you change your logic. Instead of relying on metadata in a class, add it as a `data-*` attribute which you can read directly, instead of having to sift through the applied class names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) , [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) methods and do something like this.

```
var num;
// get class attribute and split them into individual 
// and iterate
$('body').attr('class').split(' ').forEach(function(v){ 
   // check for match
   var m = v.match(/^lime-(\d+)$/);
   // if matched get the captured value
   if(m && m.length)
     num = m[1]; 
});

console.log(num);
```

---

**UPDATE :** You can make it even more simpler using much better regex.

```
var num;
var m = $('body').attr('class').match(/\(?^|\s)lime-(\d+)(?:\s|$)/);
// if matched get the captured value
if(m && m.length)
  num = m[1]; 

console.log(num);
```

Comment: @davexpression : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class and then slice out the area that you do not want. Of course, `DIV` in your case will be `body`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var classes = $('div').attr('class');
alert(classes[classes.length -1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple mango guava lime-1"><div>

</div>
```

Comment: This will work for the specific set of classnames in the example, but OP has stated they are dynamic. How will this work if the class was `apple mango foo-1 guava`?

Comment: @Rorry This solution will work if the last part is the only thing that changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[class|='lime']").attr("class").slice(-1);
```

[6.3. Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

> `[att|=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being
>   exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately followed by "-"
>   (U+002D). This is primarily intended to allow language subcode matches
>   (e.g., the hreflang attribute on the a element in HTML) as described
>   in BCP 47 ([BCP47]) or its successor. For lang (or xml:lang) language
>   subcode matching, please see the :lang pseudo-class.